# Dynamic implementation picker based in input parameters

Tags: c#, oop, generics, design-patterns

I have the following use case

```
interface IA 
{
  void Do1(Object param);
  void Do2(Object param);
}

class B : IA { ... }
class c : IA { ... }
```

what I want is to have a picker class based on input paramtes to use either classes B or C implementation. what I have done is the following. For legacy reason the Picker class must implement IA

```
class Picker : IA 
{
    Dictionary<object, IA> _mapper = new ...;


    void Do1(Object param)
    {
        _mapper[param].Do1(param);
    }

    void Do2(Object param)
    {
        _mapper[param].Do2(param);
    }
}
```

But I do not want to have the same implantation in every function in class Picker,
Is there some way around it, or some other design pattern?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you are trying to achieve - I appreciate you have tried to make it general, but may it would help if you told us your motivation/named your classes and interfaces in a more descriptive way?

Comment: The setup right now that at system strat up either I use B Or C. Now there is a new feature to use B or C On every call. so that is why I thought of using the Picker